# While editing node, format is getting messed

Tags: php, html, drupal-6

I am creating node pro-grammatically....and using FILTER HTML in format(have to convert all emails to node).
But when I am trying to edit that node again, all format like line spacing & all are getting messed up in edit box of body area..

Any clue why it is happening ?

Comment: What you've got (example), what you did, and result ... please

Comment: I am fetching emails from a mailbox and saving the body of a mail into STD Object like "$node->body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $x, 1);". This is inside the for loop, which get executed at number of times as mailbox contain the messages. Now I have used "$node->format = 1;", here 1 is for FILTERED HTML. So node is getting created correctly, but when I edit that...body text of the node in CKeditor is messed up...

Comment: did you try full html input filter?